# Read UTF-8 text in R

Tags: r

I try to read a sql file like so:

```
fileName <- paste0("C:/SomeWhere/", "test.sql")
test <- readChar(fileName, file.info(fileName)$size)
```

Unfortunately my text is in UTF-8, which look like this at the beginning:

```
ï»¿ SELECT ...
```

When I read a tab separated data text file I can use:

```
fileEncoding = "UTF-8"
```

Example:

```
some_data <- read.csv(file = "bla.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t", fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
```

Is there an equivalent to read a simple text file as one string? Thanks

Comment: `readChar` is an incredibly low-level function. You should almost never use it directly, and definitely not to read *text*.

Comment: Thanks @KonradRudolph but what is the alternative? Currently it is to save every file manually and change encoding ...

Comment: The alternative is to use the higher-level functions, such as `readLines`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read an arbitrary "text file" into R using `readLines`:

```
text <- readLines("bla.txt", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

According to `?readLines`:

> encoding
>
> encoding to be assumed for input strings. It is used to mark character
>   strings as known to be in Latin-1 or UTF-8: it is not used to
>   re-encode the input. To do the latter, specify the encoding as part of
>   the connection con or via options(encoding=): see the examples.

Maybe you need something along the lines of:

```
tryCatch({
  fileConn <- file("bla.txt", encoding = "UTF-8")
  text <- readLines(fileConn)
},
error = function(e) return(e),
finally = {
  close(fileConn)
})
```

## Edit:

Removed "-BOM" part of encoding specification, as this solved the problem.

Comment: Instead of `tryCatch` I’d generally use `on.exit` to install exit handlers such as file closing, if you’re not actually handling the error.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason it still contains ï»¿ with is the BOM bit ...

Comment: @KonradRudolph. Thanks for your comment. I agree that the `tryCatch` as used in my example is somewhat useless, since I do not handle the error (just returning the error message). If you'd like you could give an example using `on.exit` in a comment or edit/add an answer.

Comment: Maybe it should be encoding = "UTF-8"? If I remember correctly ` ï»¿` is what appears if the encoding of UTF-8 encoded files is not correctly detected. Is it possible that your "locale" is **not** "UTF-8"?